# Raspberry Pi model 4b Bluetooth issues

Tags: sound, bluetooth, bluetooth-speaker

Newbie to raspberry pi, cannot connect Bluetooth speakers after pairing using a raspberry pi model 4b GB. i have tried most of the tutorials online and YouTube , i cannot figure this out. any help is really appreciated. please provide step-to-step for solutions.

Comment: Please provide your OS & release details; are you using Ubuntu Server? Ubuntu Core? and what release of your *unstated* product.